# What's the callback for retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:'s in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy

The central manager selector `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:` replaces `retrievePeripheral:` in iOS 7.

But what callback method (central manager delegate selector) replaces `centralManager:didRetrievePeripherals:`?

`centralManager:didRetrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: I would assume the delegate callback used would be the same; have you tried it?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't take. It works if I used the deprecated selector, but then I get an empty list of peripherals. The new selector returns the correct list, but doesn't trigger the callback. Connecting directly afterwards doesn't trigger the didConnect callback... *sigh*

Comment: Hm…I'm not sure, then. :/

Comment: Oh, it returns an `NSArray`. >_>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:` returns an `NSArray` of the retrieved peripherals; no delegate callback should be needed. If you need it to be asynchronous, you could probably wrap it in a `dispatch_async()`.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought, but calling [_centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil]; with the returned peripheral (the expected one is present in the array) never calls didConnect callback like it does if I connect in the didDiscover callback.

Comment: I'm not sure; I don't have any direct experience with the Core Bluetooth stuff.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. Apparently the peripheral UUID changes every 5 min so what was correct when I snatched the UUID the first time was incorrect 5 min later. So how am one supposed to use retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers: when the peripheral UUID changes?

Comment: I think the identifier is meant to be different than the UUID? I'm not sure, though.

Comment: I also have no idea what's meant to be used for an identifier in lieu of the UUID…

Answer (score -1):

I believe your devices must be bonded for this to work correctly.